# How can I get the HotSpot and Size of the mouse cursor in C#?

Tags: c#, cursor, icons, size, mouse

How can I get the HotSpot and Size values of any mouse cursor, globally?

The following code works only in my own application:

```
Cursor.Current.HotSpot.ToString();
```

Tip for Windows API?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GetIconInfo` or `LockResource` functions. The first works with cursors as well as icons and returns an `ICONINFO` structure. The second returns a `void` pointer which can be cast to the `CURSORSHAPE` structure.